# stop accessing website content from other domain

Tags: dns, cross-domain

how can i stop accessing my website content [like image,swf,pages etc.] from other domain?
suppose my server has a myflash.swf file in my server with live url http://www.mydomain.com/flash/myflash.swf . i want this flash can't be accased by any other domain using the live url. is it possable?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If its [HotLinking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_linking) that you wish to disable, these links may help you:

> - [Htaccess Disable Hotlinking Code Generator](http://www.htmlbasix.com/disablehotlinking.shtml)
> - [Disable Hot-Linking of images and other files](http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/prevent-hot-linking.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is a HTTP header called referrer. It usually contains the site which request your swf to download.

When the Referrer value  matches your domain name name, you can serve the content. Otherwise reject it.